# Data Structure for Snapshots at Time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I've got a requirement to be able to store objects in a data structure over the course of time, and then be able to get snapshots of what the data looked like at a specific time.  I've got somewhat of a solution, but I'm wondering if there is a more optimized way to do this.  I'm thinking there may be a way to optimize the storage mechanism to not require iterating over every element to get the snapshot at that time.

In the real scenario, updates to the data can come at any time.  Objects in the data structure are indexed by Integers.  I've mocked up something quick with a Map to illustrate what I'm trying to do  (Where the arraylist is the history of updates for an object).

```
public class TimeStoreTest {

    static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Date[] dates = new Date[] { df.parse("2014-01-23 10:30:30"),
                df.parse("14-01-23 10:33:30"), df.parse("14-01-23 10:36:30"),
                df.parse("14-01-23 10:39:30"), df.parse("14-01-23 10:42:30") };

        Map<Integer, List<SimpleObject>> timeStore = new HashMap<Integer, List<SimpleObject>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
            List<SimpleObject> objs = new ArrayList<SimpleObject>();

            objs.add(new SimpleObject(i, dates[0]));
            timeStore.put(i, objs);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            List<SimpleObject> objs = new ArrayList<SimpleObject>();

            objs.add(new SimpleObject(i, dates[1]));
            timeStore.put(i, objs);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
            List<SimpleObject> objs = timeStore.get(i);
            objs.add(new SimpleObject(i, dates[2]));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
            List<SimpleObject> objs = timeStore.get(i);
            objs.add(new SimpleObject(i, dates[3]));
        }

        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            List<SimpleObject> objs = timeStore.get(i);
            objs.add(new SimpleObject(i, dates[4]));
        }

        System.out.println("Current Data Store: ");
        for (Entry<Integer, List<SimpleObject>> entry : timeStore.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }

        Date queryDate = df.parse("14-01-23 10:31:00");

        System.out.println("Query for object snapshot @ " + queryDate);
        for (SimpleObject obj : getObjectsAtTime(queryDate, timeStore)) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        queryDate = df.parse("14-01-23 10:34:30");
        System.out.println("Query for object snapshot @ " + queryDate);
        for (SimpleObject obj : getObjectsAtTime(queryDate, timeStore)) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        queryDate = df.parse("14-01-23 10:39:30");
        System.out.println("Query for object snapshot @ " + queryDate);
        for (SimpleObject obj : getObjectsAtTime(queryDate, timeStore)) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        queryDate = df.parse("14-01-23 10:42:00");

        System.out.println("Query for object snapshot @ " + queryDate);
        for (SimpleObject obj : getObjectsAtTime(queryDate, timeStore)) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

        queryDate = df.parse("14-01-23 10:45:00");

        System.out.println("Query for object snapshot @ " + queryDate);
        for (SimpleObject obj : getObjectsAtTime(queryDate, timeStore)) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

    }

    public static List<SimpleObject> getObjectsAtTime(Date date,
            Map<Integer, List<SimpleObject>> store) {
        List<SimpleObject> objectsAtTime = new ArrayList<SimpleObject>();

        for (Entry<Integer, List<SimpleObject>> entry : store.entrySet()) {

            SimpleObject previousObject = null;

            List<SimpleObject> list = entry.getValue();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                SimpleObject currentObject = list.get(i);
                if (previousObject != null) {
                    if (date.after(previousObject.updatedTime)
                            && date.before(currentObject.updatedTime)) {
                        objectsAtTime.add(previousObject);
                        break;
                    } else if (currentObject.updatedTime.equals(date)) {
                        objectsAtTime.add(currentObject);
                        break;
                    } else if (i == list.size() - 1
                            && date.after(previousObject.updatedTime)) {
                        objectsAtTime.add(currentObject);
                    }
                }

                previousObject = currentObject;
            }

        }

        return objectsAtTime;

    }
}

class SimpleObject implements Comparable {
    int id;
    Date updatedTime;

    public SimpleObject(int id, Date updatedTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.updatedTime = new Date(updatedTime.getTime());

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(object id=" + id + "; t="
                + TimeStoreTest.df.format(updatedTime) + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return updatedTime.compareTo(((SimpleObject) object).updatedTime);
    }
}
```

Results:

Current Data Store:

```
0=[(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:30:30), (object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)]
1=[(object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:33:30), (object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)]
2=[(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:30:30), (object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)]
3=[(object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:33:30), (object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)]
4=[(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:30:30), (object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)]
5=[(object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:33:30), (object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:39:30), (object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)]
6=[(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:30:30), (object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:36:30), (object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)]
7=[(object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:33:30), (object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:39:30), (object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)]
8=[(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:30:30), (object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:36:30), (object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)]
9=[(object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:33:30), (object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:39:30), (object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)]
Query for object snapshot @ Thu Jan 23 10:31:00 PST 2014
(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
Query for object snapshot @ Thu Jan 23 10:34:30 PST 2014
(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:33:30)
(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:33:30)
(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:33:30)
(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:33:30)
(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:30:30)
(object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:33:30)
Query for object snapshot @ Thu Jan 23 10:39:30 PST 2014
(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
Query for object snapshot @ Thu Jan 23 10:42:00 PST 2014
(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
Query for object snapshot @ Thu Jan 23 10:45:00 PST 2014
(object id=0; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=1; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=2; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=3; t=14-01-23 10:39:30)
(object id=4; t=14-01-23 10:36:30)
(object id=5; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)
(object id=6; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)
(object id=7; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)
(object id=8; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)
(object id=9; t=14-01-23 10:42:30)
```

So, you can see that it works, but I'm trying to find ways to make this more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with an interval tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) with each segment being mapped to a HashMap of objects active at that time.

I modified this code for my usage:

https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/blogspot/software_and_algorithms/stern_library/data_structure/DynamicIntervalTree.java

Answer (score 1):

Using a NavigableMap would probably make your life easier. Have a look for example at [`TreeMap#floorEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) which does something similar to your `getObjectsAtTime` method.

It has other method such as `subMap` which may be handy too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This looks like it would be a good replacement for the ArrayList itself, but is there a way to leverage this across the whole data set?

Comment: If you have more than one entry for a given time you will need to stick to using an ArrayList as a value I'm afraid... The idea is to replace your HashMap by a TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use a TreeMap and then call subMap to query on the date range you want like this

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class KeyRange {

  static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Date[] dates = new Date[]{df.parse("2014-01-23 10:30:30"),
      df.parse("14-01-23 10:33:30"), df.parse("14-01-23 10:36:30"),
      df.parse("14-01-23 10:39:30"), df.parse("14-01-23 10:42:30")};
/**
 * use a treeMap, because it has sorted keys and it can be queried with from -> to values
 */
    TreeMap<Date, Object> data = new TreeMap<>();
    for(Date d : dates){
      data.put(d, null);
    }
    /**
     * use the subMap function to "query" the map by a range of sorted keys...this would be your query time span
     */
    NavigableMap<Date, Object> queryResult = data.subMap(df.parse("14-01-23 10:33:30"), true,  df.parse("14-01-23 10:39:30"), false);
    System.out.println(queryResult);
  }
}
```

the result of above is this

{Thu Jan 23 10:33:30 EST 2014=null, Thu Jan 23 10:36:30 EST 2014=null}

if you want it sorted descending, then add .descendingMap() to the end of the submap method